# Select all elements that share a class but do not have a specific id

Tags: jquery

For example, let's say I have 3 elements:

```
<p class="content" id="p1"> </p>
<p class="content" id="p2"> </p>
<p class="content" id="p3"> </p>
```

I know that to select the content elements I would use `$('.content')`, and to select the `p1` element I would use `$('#p1')`. My question is - how do I select all of the content elements that are *not* `p1`?

I've tried `$('.content:not[#p1])`, but that didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### `:not()` Selector

> **Description**: *Selects all elements that do not match the given selector*.
>
> `jQuery( ":not(selector)" )`
> `selector`: A selector with which to filter by.
>
> All selectors are accepted inside `:not()`, for example: `:not(div a)` and `:not(div,a)`.

Source: https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/

---

```js
$(".content:not(#p1)").each(function() {
    console.log(this.id);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="content" id="p1"> </p>
<p class="content" id="p2"> </p>
<p class="content" id="p3"> </p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
$('.content').not('#p1');
```